# Issue of multiple opened Excel files with same shortcut

Tags: excel, vba, shortcut

I have multiple Excel files, which have the macros assigned the same shortcut. When I open these files simultaneously and run macro via shorcut，by debug in VBE, I found that it will always run the macro which is in the first-opened file instead of the macro itself. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The fix is to use different shortcuts for the macros. In one Excel instance you can have a shortcut only assigned to one single procedure. Shortcuts are assigned per Excel instance not per file.

The other workaround is to ensure the files are opened in different Excel instances. Different instances behave like 2 entirely seperate Excel applications.

A new instance can be opened by keeping the <kbd>Alt</kbd> button on the keyboard pressed while launching a second Excel.
Also see [How to open multiple instances of Excel](https://exceloffthegrid.com/how-to-open-multiple-instances-of-excel/).

If you have 2 different instances every Excel instance has its own application settings and therefore the shortcut runs only the macro of the instance that has focus while you press the shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is **to assign the shortcuts programmatically and to dynamically enable/disable them** when a workbook becomes active/inactive. In this way you can make sure that the shortcuts are only enabled in one workbook, namely the active one, at a time.

Here is how I have solved it:

Put this in the *ThisWorkbook* module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    'Debug.Print "Workbook got activated"
    Call KeyboardShortcuts(True)
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    'Debug.Print "Workbook got deactivated"
    Call KeyboardShortcuts(False)
End Sub
```

This can be put in an arbitrary code module:

```
Function KeyboardShortcuts(assign As Boolean)
    ' There is a problem when you assign keyboard shortcuts to macros through the macros menu:
    ' When there are multiple Excel workbooks open in the same instance of the Excel application,
    ' it is possible that when you enter a keyboard shortcut in workbook A, it gets captured from workbook B.
    ' This can lead to undesired results.
    ' So we do it like this:
    ' keyboard shortcuts are enabled when the workbook gets activated and
    '              they are disabled when the workbook gets deactivated.
    Dim Keydef As String
    Dim Keys() As String
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim pair() As String
    
    Keydef = "+^W:Function1_KB" & _
       "|" & "+^D:Function2_KB" & _
       "|" & "+^F:Function3_KB" & _
       "|" & "+^G:Function4_KB" & _
       "|" & "+^L:Function5_KB" & _
       "|" & "+^P:Function6_KB" & _
       "|" & "+^T:Function7_KB" & _
       ""

    Keys = Split(Keydef, "|")
    
    For Each item In Keys
        pair = Split(item, ":")
        
        If assign = True Then
            ' Enable the keyboard shortcut:
            Application.OnKey pair(0), pair(1)
        Else
            ' Disable the keyboard shortcut:
            Application.OnKey pair(0)
        End If
    Next
    
End Function

Function Function1_KB()
   Debug.Print "You have pressed Shft+Ctrl+W"
End Function
...
Function Function7_KB()
   Debug.Print "You have pressed Shft+Ctrl+T"
End Function
```

Comment: Note that if you open only one workbook (eg from an external source you do not control) that assigns shortcuts in a different way it gets messed up and won't work properly anymore. This idea can only work if all workbooks you open (and have shortcuts) are in your full control. • Aside from that, this would be a nice workaround. Note that instead of using a `String` to split you can directly use an array: `Keydef = Array("+^W:Function1_KB", "+^D:Function2_KB")` or even `Keydef = Array(Array("+^W", "Function1_KB"), Array("+^D", "Function2_KB"))` which is less hungry.